# Has Spring boot something like JEE ManagedExecutorService?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot for programming microservices with a high number of request.
The last nigth i see an example of ManagedExecutorService in a JEE microservice and i try to find something similar in Spring framework for use but i can't find it.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score -1):

The ManagedExecutorService is simply a wrapper for the [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) because JEE applications are not permitted to create unmanaged threads.

Just use the [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) in your Spring boot micro service.